# Conditionally-compiling based on endianness

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, endianness

I'm reading `Word`s from byte arrays and need to make parts of my code endian-aware. Does GHC expose anything (like `MachDeps.h`) which I can use to make code conditional on processor endianness? If not can I deduce endianness reliably from `HOST_ARCH` (from `ghcplatform.h` accessible in .cabal file with the `arch()` conditional)? Or other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpu-0.1.0/docs/System-Endian.html

If you don't want/cannot use these packages, looking at the source code for the above, you can see how to check endianness on any platform with (almost) any lower-level programming language like C or similar. Fill a part of your stack (for a machine with 4 bits: e.g. 1000) and then read back the LSB or MSB of said stack. The Endianness will determine how it is stored (you'll read back 1000 or 0001).

Comment: Thanks! I'd sort of ruled that out for performance reasons, but I should look more closely. I think I could at least do that trick in some template haskell to get a compile-time constant.